# Is there a better and quick way of processing requests from a list of requests?

Tags: lists, mobile-application, user-centered-design, listview

I am making an mobile app where there is a list of requests for points towards a client and the client assigns a desired number of points to each request.
The client sees all the requests in chronological order. these can be from various number of users. when he selects a requests he can assign points to it and send the points. well this process seems to work when there are less number of requests, but when there are around 50 requests it becomes difficult and a tedious process. I would like to know how can I design this situation in a manner that the process of assigning points because quick for the client, and he doesn't have to spend a lot of time in processing them.

> Request List

[image: List of requests to the client]

> Assigning point to a request

[image: assign points to the request]

Answer (score 2):

## Use filters to view outstanding items, and an archive can show a 'Sent' history and timestamp.

Since you have a potentially long list, give the power of filtering, so that states that are urgent 'Pending', 'Waiting', etc... are shown with the number of items outstanding.

#### Filter the view so long lists can be dealt with.

[image]
**If you have their address, you can batch the amounts if possible.**

If you have some standard (common) amounts you find get sent constantly, allow them to batch at once. (This only works if you already have their contact info)

[image]

#### Another approach: open input fields for entering points (Single actions).

You could also keep the input fields open, and show the buttons in a muted state. Once they enter, the <kbd>Send</kbd> button changes to indicate you are able to send.

[image]

Comment: An elegant solution, as usual.

Comment: please feel free to beat this up to improve it.